# Hide referrer Redirect Script - As nullrefer.com

Tags: php, redirect, hide, referrer

I'm trying to create a script that redirects with a null referrer. I'm trying to do something like this website: http://nullrefer.com/

I want it so it's like this:
(Example)
http://mysite.com/redirect.php?url=http://google.com

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: What is the specific question / problem you have?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the question correctly, you want to send the visitor away from the site if they were not referred to you from another site (if they typed your URL in directly)

you would want something like...

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
    header('Location: http://google.com');
```

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question... you want to be able to be a pass-through site where people will link to a site making it look like you were the referrer